# Whatever that can be done using algorithm can be done using Turing machine

Tags: computability, turing-machines, church-turing-thesis

In 1937 how was Alan Turing so sure that all that can be done using algorithms can be implemented using a Turing machine?
Since that period many new algorithms were implemented. What was his hypothesis behind this theory ?

Comment: Did you read Turing's 1936 paper "On computable numbers" (e.g. [here](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf))? Paragraph 9 addresses *exactly* this question and is quite clear and readable.

Comment: Common researcher's reasoning: "I'm an expert and I can not imagine a way. So I conjecture it's impossible."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hypotesis is the following:

"Since an algorithm is a well-defined sequence of steps we can always execute an algorithm in a piece of paper(sometimes we may need a really big paper) using a pencil."

Then he created the Turing Machine who can simulate a hand using a pencil with an infinite paper.